# Is there any way to automatically Delete/Remove Push notification after 2 hours in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I tried many ways to do that from the app and from the server but didn't get success.

Comment: I don't think _your app_ can delete the notification from _Notification Centre_. The notifications just get stacked inside _Notification Centre_ unless the user manually removes it

Comment: you can send a silent push notification with collapse-id for the notification that you want to remove from device Notification centre. When you receive notification in your service extension, you can fetch the notification for the collapse-id and remove it. It would look similar to what Whatsapp does.

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi I think you don't know about "collapse-id" and "apns-id", that's why your answer is not worthy.

Comment: @manishsharma93 Yes you are right, I tried that way but not able to delete the notification. Do you have a sample code to do that from the PHP side?

Comment: Why is this question, and questions like this, downvoted? It seems like a useful feature to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Managing Delivered Notifications**

> When local and remote notifications are not handled directly by your app or the user, they are displayed in Notification Center so that they can be viewed later. Use the getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler: method of the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object to get a list of notifications still being displayed in Notification Center. If you find any notifications that are now outdated and should not be displayed to the user, you can remove them using the removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers: method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1

Send a silent push notification in which you have to get all the notifications of your app from notification canter and remove them according to your need.